# Speedy complex Pandas & dictionary manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to Pandas and seeking some advice on a tricky pivot table manipulation please.

I have two Pandas pivot tables and a dictionary. The first pivot table has some values that are zero. The second pivot table has the same factors and levels but different values. The dictionary is a set of all possible level pairs for each factor. Sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MyColumn1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'MyColumn2': ['M', 'N', 'M', 'P'],
                   'Value': [1, 1, 1, 1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['MyColumn1', 'MyColumn2'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value = 0, dropna = False)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'MyColumn1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'MyColumn2': ['M', 'N', 'P', 'M', 'N', 'P'],
                   'Value': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]})
table2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='Value', index=['MyColumn1', 'MyColumn2'], aggfunc=np.sum)

myDictionary = {'MyColumn1': {('A', 'A'): 10, ('A', 'B'): 20, 
                  ('B', 'A'): 30, ('B', 'B'): 40},
        'MyColumn2': {('M', 'M'): 1, ('M', 'N'): 2, ('M', 'P'): 3,
                  ('N', 'M'): 4, ('N', 'N'): 5, ('N', 'P'): 6,
                  ('P', 'M'): 7, ('P', 'N'): 8, ('P', 'P'): 9}}
```

This code generates the following tables:

```
TABLE                Value
MyColumn1 MyColumn2       
A         M              1
          N              1
          P              0
B         M              1
          N              0
          P              1

TABLE2               Value
MyColumn1 MyColumn2       
A         M              5
          N             10
          P             15
B         M             20
          N             25
          P             30
```

For every non-zero entry in the `Table`, I'd like to (1) go through every zero entry in the `Table` and find the product of the numbers in myDictionary that correspond to the zero entry key and the non-zero entry key, (2) multiply each product by the corresponding value in `Table2` for the zero'd row, and then (3) find the sum of these products.

For instance, with the data above, the algorithm would calculate:

```
(A, P) -> (A, M) = 10 * 7 = 70, 70 * 15 = 1050
(A, P) -> (A, N) = 10 * 8 = 80, 80 * 15 = 1200
(A, P) -> (B, M) = 20 * 7 = 140, 140 * 15 = 2100
(A, P) -> (B, P) = 20 * 9 = 180, 180 * 15 = 2700

(B, N) -> (A, M) = 30 * 4 = 120, 120 * 25 = 3000
(B, N) -> (A, N) = 30 * 5 = 150, 150 * 25 = 3750
(B, N) -> (B, M) = 40 * 4 = 160, 160 * 25 = 4000
(B, N) -> (B, P) = 40 * 6 = 240, 240 * 25 = 6000
```

The first four rows correspond to the first zero entry, and the second four rows correspond to the second zero entry in the `Table`. There are four rows because there are four non-zero entries. Next, the algorithm multiplies by the corresponding value in `Table2`. Finally, it would add up for each non-zero entry:

```
(A, M) total = 1050 + 3000 = 4050
(A, N) total = 1200 + 3750 = 4950
(B, M) total = 2100 + 4000 = 6100
(B, P) total = 2700 + 6000 = 8700
```

The desired result is a pivot table of the same shape as the original table but with these sums as the values.

```
                     Value
MyColumn1 MyColumn2       
A         M           4050
          N           4950
          P              0
B         M           6100
          N              0
          P           8700
```

I am looking for a way to do this efficiently because, in practice, I will have 100,000+ zero entries, <1000 non-zero entries, and ~10 columns. I'm not sure how to structure the loops for performance reasons, or even if loops are the most efficient way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how fast this is on your actual data, but this is what I would do:

```
col1_df = pd.Series(myDictionary['MyColumn1']).unstack()
col2_df = pd.Series(myDictionary['MyColumn2']).unstack()

out_df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop through columns
for col in table.columns:    
    zeros = table['Value'].eq(0)
    non_zero_idx = np.array(table.index[~zeros].to_list())
    zero_idx = np.array(table.index[zeros].to_list())

    num_nz, num_z = len(non_zero_idx), len(zero_idx)

    xs,ys = np.meshgrid(np.arange(num_z),np.arange(num_nz))
    xs, ys = xs.ravel(), ys.ravel()

    col1 = col1_df.lookup(zero_idx[xs,0], non_zero_idx[ys,0])
    col2 = col2_df.lookup(zero_idx[xs,1], non_zero_idx[ys,1])

    prods = (col1* col2).reshape(num_nz, num_z).T

    values = table2.loc[zeros, ['Value']].values

    out_df[col] = (pd.Series((prods * values).sum(0), index=non_zero_idx)
                     .reindex(table.index, fill_value=0)
                  )
```

Output:

```
                     Value
MyColumn1 MyColumn2       
A         M           4050
          N           4950
          P              0
B         M           6100
          N              0
          P           8700
```